# What are the procedural differences in calling a general election "notwithstanding the FTPA"?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, brexit, house-of-commons

I have seen suggestions in several places now that the government may try to pass a one-line bill reading: "Notwithstanding the Fixed-term Parliaments Act, we will have a general election on 15 October."  How, procedurally, would this differ from calling a general election normally, either with a 2/3 vote in the House of Commons or by a successful motion of no confidence?  What obstacles for the government would it avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How, procedurally, would this differ from calling a general election normally, either with a 2/3 vote in the House of Commons or by a successful motion of no confidence?

If the proposed Bill passes, then it becomes an Act with full force in law and effectively bypasses the [Fixed Term Parliaments Act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2011/14/enacted) - a bill only requires a majority to pass.

The FTPA sets out four ways in which Parliament can pass *motions* in order to call a general election - motions do not become Acts, and do not pass into law.  Motions called under the FTPA require a two thirds majority in order to pass and trigger the requisite actions required.

> What obstacles for the government would it avoid?

Looking at the wording of the FTPA, I think this is the main obstacle that the bill would overcome:

> (1) The Parliament then in existence dissolves at the beginning of the 17th working day before the polling day for the next parliamentary general election as determined under section 1 or appointed under section 2(7).
>
> (2) ***Parliament cannot otherwise be dissolved.***

*Section 3, FTPA*

The emphasised line may create legal issues for Johnson with his intention to prorogue Parliament as it would essentially give Parliament an additional week of debating - calling an election using an Act would avoid any potential legal issues around this, and essentially allow him to dissolve Parliament whenever he wanted.